# Optimizing DAX Has X Amount or More in Time Frame

Tags: performance, powerbi, dax, measure

I am looking to speed up this calculation that takes a minute or two to load each time I add a different filter view on the page.

The base measure just calculates the total logins in a rolling 3 month which works as expected.

```
TotalLoginsIn90 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Logins] ),
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Calendar'[Date], LASTDATE ( Logins[Date] ), -3, MONTH )
)
```

I am now looking to identify in each month the amount of users that make over 3 logins in each month.

```
CustLoginIn90 =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( DISTINCT ( Logins[Customer Number)] ), 1 ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Logins[Cust Customer Number (Numeric)] ),
        [TotalLoginsIn90] > 3
    )
)
```

or

```
CustLoginIn90 =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCT ( Logins[Customer Number] ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Logins[Cust Customer Number (Numeric)] ),
        [TotalLoginsIn90] > 3
    )
)
```

each of these takes its sweet time to calculate but ends up with the correct amount.

Is there any way to speed up these measures?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How many rows are in your `Logins` table?

Comment: Roughly 100k customers per month. The Login table is as optimized as I can go which is Month/Customer/Number of logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making the `TotalLoginsIn90` as a calculated column instead of a measure so it only needs to be calculated once (per report refresh).

```
TotalLoginsIn90 = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Logins] ),
    DATESINPERIOD (Logins[Date], Logins[Date], -3, MONTH)
)
```

That also allows you to write a very simple condition for your `CustLoginIn90` measure:

```
CustLoginIn90 = SUMX(Logins, IF(Logins[TotalLogins90] > 3, 1, 0))
```

Comment: When I filter down to a unique customer in the Logins table it is only showing the logins for the row for the calculated column TotalLoginsIn90. CustLoginIn90  is the same as if I were to count rows where transactions is >3.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can you show what you're getting versus what you'd expect?

Comment: I had to change the measure to CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Logins[Cust Customer Number (Numeric)]), Logins[TotalLoginsIn90] > 3) due to wanting unique users. I also added the calculated column to include an Earlier TotalLoginsIn90 = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Logins[MblTrans Number of Activities] ),
     DATESINPERIOD (Logins[Date], Logins[Date], -3, MONTH),FILTER(Logins,Logins[Cust Customer Number (Numeric)] = EARLIER(Logins[Cust Customer Number (Numeric)]))
).  Doing it with the calculated column made it go 100x quicker when i started to filter on the data. Thank you for the head start!